# Jquery, prevent queuing animations

Tags: jquery, queue, jquery-animate

I have a div which fades In/Out another element on the page on hover (and hover out). The trouble is there's nothing to stop the user hovering over and out really quickly and causing the animation to queue up.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="hovertest">test</div>

<div class="test">test2</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("div.hovertest").hover(
      function () {
        $(".test").fadeOut();
      }, 
      function () {
        $(".test").fadeIn();
});
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#B22;
}
```

And here's a link to jsfidde: http://jsfiddle.net/btEXH/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function and pass true for clearQueue and jumpToEnd.

```
$("div.hovertest").hover(
  function () {
    $(".test").stop(true, true).fadeOut();
  }, 
  function () {
    $(".test").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/btEXH/1/

Comment: Is it possible to fadeIn/Out from where the animation stopped rather than jumping to the end and then running the animation. - that's done the job otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: @Tom It should be possible by changing the 2nd parameter to false. Although that seems to cause opacity problems

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and got the same problem. In this case it shouldn't cause a problem but if the animation was slower it might look a bit odd.

Comment: @Tom You can fix that problem by specifying the target opacity using `fadeTo` http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/btEXH/2/